# proper alignment is not working in bootsrap navbar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, alignment

When I use bootstrap navbar I got an issue when that uses for the extra small screen.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbFmZ.png)

Comment: add some CSS your code is fine

Comment: Can we see some code?

Comment: i got the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have `.text-right` or something with `text-align: right;` on the nav items?

If you do, changing to `.text-center` or `text-align: center;` will work (perhaps put it in a `@media` to set for the responsive nav only).

It would also help to add some of your code to the question.